# Combine/merge factors of variable in R deducer

Tags: r, user-interface

Just for curiosity...

I'm creating a contingency table in R Deducer using a variable with three factor levels, e.g. *yes, no, undecided* but I would like to know if there is a Gui way of combining two levels so there would be e.g. *decided, undecided*? I just downloaded Deducer and it looks good (I'm a little lost) but I'm curious to know how much I can mine my data without leaving the program and avoid programming.

(I wouldn't mind if an R script would follow though I could fix this in many ways without it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recode the levels of your factor to combine the two categories using the "recode" dialog. see: http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.RecodeVariables

Comment: Yes, I had noticed but the `Set Variable Codings` window wasn't n00b enough for me. I get it now. By the way, are plotting issues common in Deducer? I'm having troubles with all plots, integers are read as discrete.